# Is it possible to have two independent VPNs working on one system?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I am trying to create two independent VPNs on Ubuntu 22.04 and I am not sure it's possible.

VPN #1 is initialized on the terminal with the command 'vpn_service connect'. This creates an interface under the name of the vpn_service with an IP of 10.5.0.2.

VPN #2 is initialized using a GUI client. I select the server and attempt to connect. This does not ever connect, irrespective of the protocol (UDP, TCP, Wireguard).

(I don't want to have a browser extension. I want VPN #2 to tunnel all traffic).

The VPN #2 attempts to create an interface on wlp0s20f3 which is the standard wireless interface (so nothing related to VPN #1).

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

I have disabled the 'ufw' firewall for these tests.

```
  2023.04.01 23:57:06   Routes, add 217.138.xxx.xxx/32 for interface "wlp0s20f3", already exists.
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2022
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]217.138.xxx.xxx:443
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > UDP link local: (not bound)
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > UDP link remote: [AF_INET]217.138.xxx.xxx:443
. 2023.04.01 23:57:06 - OpenVPN > write UDP: Operation not permitted (code=1)
. 2023.04.01 23:57:08 - OpenVPN > write UDP: Operation not permitted (code=1)
. 2023.04.01 23:57:13 - OpenVPN > write UDP: Operation not permitted (code=1)
. 2023.04.01 23:57:38 - Above log line repeated 2 times more
. 2023.04.01 23:57:38 - OpenVPN > [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-exit), exiting
. 2023.04.01 23:57:38 - OpenVPN > SIGTERM received, sending exit notification to peer
. 2023.04.01 23:57:43 - OpenVPN > SIGTERM[soft,exit-with-notification] received, process exiting
! 2023.04.01 23:57:43 - Disconnecting
```

Comment: If the VPN clients and the VP endpoint termination are entirely different and do not conflict when both are loaded, it is possible.  I have done it with NCP and Sonic Wall VPN.  If the same VPN client App, probably not.

Comment: @John - They are different VPNs. One is run via command line and the other via a GUI. But the GUI does not work on Ubuntu. It does work on another OS.